# Django - reload only body page using block not refresh whole page

Tags: javascript, html, django, block

**base.html**

```
<body class="skin-red">
    <!-- Site wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- #HEADER -->
        {% include 'HEADER.html' %}
        <!-- /#HEADER -->

        <!-- #SIDEBAR -->
        {% include 'SIDEBAR.html' %}
        <!-- /#SIDEBAR -->

        <!-- #BODY -->
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

        <!-- /#BODY -->

        <!-- #FOOTER -->
        {% include 'FOOTER.html' %}
        <!-- /#FOOTER -->


        {% block extrajavascript %}
        {% endblock %}

  </body>
```

**HEADER.html**:

```
  <header class="main-header">
    <a href="/rm" class="logo"><b>Resource</b> Monitor <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" style="color:#ffd400"></i></a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/rm">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/rm/pcinfo"> PC information </a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_sysuse">??? ???</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_procuse">???? ???</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_prodet">???? ????</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_sdwt">SDWT ????</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_pcevents">??? ?? ??</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_winevents">??? ?? ID? ??</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_agentinfo">Agent ????</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Email ?? ?? <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_emailconfigs">??? ??</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_emailreceiver">??? ??</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

When I click header tab menu, I want to reload only 
 `{% block content %}`
 `{% endblock %}`
 not whole pages.. but now It reloaded the whole page.. 
There are formbox in my side bar and there are some values which user input. so I don't want to loose my user input by refresh whole page. Is there any solution..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need javascript AJAX api to get the content and change the html content using javascript DOM api if you need "without reload" function.

> Django or any application server or http webserver works in a
>   request-response way, when a response is returned to the browser, the
>   server has no control to the client.

Comment: Thanks! I do return json at wiew.py and reload only div using ajax,